# giving result with repetition of three times for the same. CodeIgniter PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, join

This query giving same result 3 times. i couldn't identify the error. I am using codeigniter. The query in the function in model is

**Model**

```
public function combinedFunctionTest($userID){
        $this->db->from('test_report');
        $this->db->join('assign_tble','test_report.scode=assign_tble.scode','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('course_details','test_report.ccode=course_details.ccode','LEFT');
        $this->db->where('test_report.scode',$userID);
        $query=$this->db->get();            
        return $query->result();    
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function results()
{
    $this->load->model('AllCourses_m');
    $data['records']=$this->AllCourses_m-> combinedFunctionTest('2420DC');
    $this->load->view('courses/TestResult',$data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
foreach ($records as $rec) {
    ?>
    <tr>


        <td>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $rec->ccode; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $rec->cname; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $rec->adate; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rec->at_date; ?></td>

        <td>
            <?php echo $rec->score; ?>
        </td>


    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Why this is resulting three times repetition for the same. anybody can help me?

Comment: May be you have multiple entries in `course_details` for same `course_details`

Comment: there is no multiple entrees and here test report is the first table @B.Desai

Comment: use group_by for single record

Comment: How and Where? Could you show an example with my code?@GopalBhuva

Comment: add this line after where condition in model : $this->db->group_by('test_report.scode');

Comment: while giving this group this is showing the result without repetition. but one column which joined from table assign_tble is showing same only. that means result from that is repeating still. how can i solve this? @GopalBhuva